# Is it legal to intentionally manipulate a person towards suicide?

Tags: murder, suicide

I think this should count as murder (attempted murder if the victim does not fall prey that is), since there is an intention to kill and the process is plotted and carried out ruthless with extraordinary care and profound understanding of human psychology on the killer's part. But legal definition of murder often refers to UNWILLINGNESS on the victim's part. So I'm very confused.

I have two other questions: is there truly a legal path to prosecute the killer and has any of such killer actually been caught and punished? If so, what type of evidence would be needed in the court to make such act prosecutable?

I'm more interested in US law but cases in other countries are welcome as well

Comment: There is great variation on this issue from jurisdiction to jurisdiction, and in many, if not most, jurisdictions, it is an unsettled or unresolved point of law. So this question verges on being overbroad. Also, even if this conduct is a crime that crime it isn't always "murder." For example, some U.S. states have a specific crime of "assisting suicide" which is serious but not as serious as murder. There are examples of people being convicted of crimes for this kind of conduct, although usually not first degree murder, under these circumstances. Many other facts are often relevant.

Comment: Also, even when something isn't a crime, it can still be illegal and for example, provide a basis for a wrongful death civil lawsuit.

Comment: @ohwilleke Bur from a purely academic point view, such action could qualify as capital murder right? For example, if a diary of the manipulator is found where she explicitly outlined her goal as manipulating the victim to death and detailed all her plans and motivations, should that warrant a murder trial?

Comment: Usually not. It turns on the language of the statute in the particular state. For example, in Colorado when a "person intentionally causes or aids another person to commit suicide" (subject to certain exceptions), Section 18-3-104(1)(b), Colorado Revised Statutes, that is manslaughter, a class 4 felony punishable by four to twelve years in prison (usually reduced 25% for good behavior in prison), and not murder.

Comment: "legal definition of murder often refers to UNWILLINGNESS on the victim's part": can you cite an example?

Comment: @ohwilleke to show that an act isn't murder, don't you have to identify some element of that crime that isn't satisfied by the act? That the elements of a lesser crime are satisfied does not prevent the elements of the greater crime from being satisfied as well.

Comment: @phoog In this case, the more specific statute in context of the whole criminal code leads to an interpretation of the murder statute that "causes" death means personally physically causes a death rather than merely causing someone else to do that (an interpretation also supported by the criminal solicitation statute). There can be lesser included offenses but it would be a very unnatural reading in CO.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, but it is its own crime [new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales) [australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

[s31C(2)](http://www8.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ca190082/s31c.html) of the Crimes Act 1900:

> 2) Where:
>
> (a) a person incites or counsels another person to commit suicide, and
>
> (b) that other person commits, or attempts to commit, suicide as a consequence of that incitement or counsel,
>
> the first-mentioned person shall be liable to imprisonment for 5 years.

An enthusiastic prosecutor could *try* to get a murder ([s18(1)(a)](http://www8.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ca190082/s18.html)) conviction:

> (a) Murder shall be taken to have been committed where the act of the accused, or thing by him or her omitted to be done, causing the death charged, was done or omitted with reckless indifference to human life, or with intent to kill or inflict grievous bodily harm upon some person, or done in an attempt to commit, or during or immediately after the commission, by the accused, or some accomplice with him or her, of a crime punishable by imprisonment for life or for 25 years.

The difficulty with this is that it would be difficult to prove beyond a reasonable doubt that the accused *caused* the death.

Comment: To show that the described conduct isn't murder, wouldn't you have to examine the murder statute?  That a given act satisfies the elements of one specific crime does not exclude the possibility that it also satisfies the elements of another crime.

Comment: @phoog good point - will do